# biblatex-apa error with silence package, is it innocuous?

Tags: biblatex, errors

I am getting the following compilation errors when using `biblatex`, APA and `silence`. I hope it is not harmful? I just updated my MiKTeX distribution and reinstalled `biblatex-apa`.

```
[ ERROR ][ C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX
2.9\tex\latex\biblatex-apa\apa.bbx | Line 972 ] Argument of \blx@noline has an extra }:    \renewbibmacro*{reviewauthor}

[ WARNING ][ C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX
2.9\tex\latex\biblatex-apa\apa.bbx | Line  ] Runaway argument?   ! Paragraph ended before \blx@noline was complete.

[ ERROR ][ C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX
2.9\tex\latex\biblatex-apa\apa.bbx | Line 972 ] Paragraph ended before \blx@noline was complete:    \renewbibmacro*{reviewauthor}

[ WARNING ][ C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX
2.9\tex\latex\biblatex-apa\apa.bbx | Line  ] Package biblatex Warning: Macro 'reviewauthor' undefined.(biblatex)                Using \newbibmacro.
```

Here a MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{standalone} 
\usepackage{silence}
\usepackage[log-declarations=false]{xparse}
\usepackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
\begin{document}
Testing
\end{document}
```

Comment: A `Runaway argument?` error means TeX got confused and some arbitrary portion of your document might have been dropped before TeX managed to recover its idea of your `{}` matching. It may be that it wasn't as confused as it thought it was but I would not consider using the generated output of such a run for anything other than debugging where the problem is. Does your MWE really show the problem? I get no errors with xelatex xelatex biber xelatex on that file.

Comment: Yes I got the error with MWE with xelatex? I tried deleting the aux file and compiled again.

Comment: don't just delete the aux file delete all the .bbx .bbl etc (everything except the tex)

Comment: still the same errors?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quite probably it *isn't* innocuous. And, of course, the choice between not having warnings and not having errors is easy to make. `;-)`

The problem is due to the fact that "NoLine" warnings usually are obtained by adding `\@gobble` at the end of a `\PackageWarning` argument:

```
% latex.ltx, line 972:
\def\PackageWarningNoLine#1#2{%
   \PackageWarning{#1}{#2\@gobble}%
}
```

However, `biblatex` uses its own way:

```
% biblatex2.sty, line 728:
\protected\def\blx@warning#1{%
  \begingroup
  \blx@safe@actives
  \PackageWarning{biblatex}{#1\blx@noline}%
  \endgroup}
```

where `\blx@noline` is defined to be the same as `\@gobble` (but it's made equivalent to `\@empty` later on):

```
% biblatex2.sty, line 754:
\let\blx@noline\@gobble
```

So the methods `silence` uses for neutralizing `\@gobble` don't work with `biblatex`.

You can patch the `silence` macros to recognize also `\blx@noline`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article} 
\usepackage{silence}
\WarningsOff[biblatex]

\makeatletter
% New macro
\def\sl@RemoveBlxNoline#1\blx@noline\sl@Terminator#2\sl@Terminator{%
  \def\sl@Tempb{#2}%
  \ifx\sl@Tempb\@empty
  \else
    \def\sl@Tempa{#1}%
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \fi
  }
\def\sl@StoreMessage#1{%
  \ifsl@SafeMode
    \sl@UnexpandedMessage{#1}%
  \else
    \sl@UnexpandedMessage{#1}%
    \begingroup
    \let\protect\string
    \let\noexpand\string
    \def\sl@Tempa{#1}%
    \sl@RemoveGobble#1\sl@Terminator\@gobble\sl@Terminator\sl@Terminator
    \sl@RemoveGobbletwo#1\sl@Terminator\@gobbletwo\sl@Terminator\sl@Terminator
    %%% ADDED TEST
    \sl@RemoveBlxNoline#1\sl@Terminator\blx@noline\sl@Terminator\sl@Terminator
    %%%
    \edef\sl@Tempa{\sl@Tempa}%
    \global\expandafter\sl@Message\expandafter{\sl@Tempa}%
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\makeatother

\usepackage[log-declarations=false]{xparse}
\usepackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
\begin{document}
Testing
\end{document}
```

In this way the warning

```
Package biblatex Warning: Macro 'reviewauthor' undefined.
(biblatex)                Using \newbibmacro.
```

that you get without the `silence` package disappears.

You should make a feature request to the maintainer of `silence`.

Comment: @MobiusPizza You could make a feature request to the maintainer of `silence`: the patch is along the lines that are used in the package, so integrating it should be easy.

Comment: That's very helpful, I have also sent an email to the maintainer of silence package. Thanks.

Comment: Off topic but I tried and failed to find why the warning above regarding `reviewauthor` is given by biblatex-apa, `reviewauthor` is not in the `biblatex` manual. I guess that is another topic of its own unless anyone has a short answer.

Comment: Odd. I got no error with the MWE, I suppose I have an older or newer version? (I'm using TL2012)

Comment: The warning suggests that biblatex-apa uses `\renewbibmacro{reviewauthor}` where it should use `\newbibmacro{reviewauthor}` precisely because "standard" biblatex doesn't define that `bibmacro`. As such *that warning* is *usually* innocuous, though the maintainer of `biblatex-apa` (PLK) will probably want to clean it up.

Comment: @PaulStanley With my "innocuous" I was referring to the errors not to the warning itself, which really is.

Comment: @egreg Absolutely: that's why I wrote *that warning*; sorry if I wasn't clear. The error in the MWE when silence is loaded is certainly not innocuous! But the warning which had triggered the noxious error is probably not something that one should worry about in itself. Put differently: the serious problem is with `silence` not with `biblatex-apa`.

Comment: This reviewauthor problem will be fixed in the next biblatex-apa release.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks for providing the patch! Please see also https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/47.